# Mount Block Device in LXD

Tags: linux, mount, lxc, containers

I have been experimenting with LXD on Ubuntu Server 16.04 and i'm trying to figure out how to mount a linux block device from the host in the container. I was able to successfully add the device using the command:

`lxc config device add test sdb1 unix-block path=/dev/sdb1`

When i attach to the container and run `ls /dev/` i can see that `sdb1` exists but i am unable to mount it within the container.

I have tried running `mount /dev/sdb1 testdir/` but I get the error:
`mount: permission denied`

Am I setting this up correctly? If so how would I mount inside to container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the container usually maps its UIDs on top of the hosts UID 100000 (which would map to the UID of the containers "root" user), so I guess you need to make sure this uid is on the host system allowed to mount the block device.

**EDIT**

perhaps this blog helps you with the problem: http://www.forshee.me/2016/02/22/container-mounts-in-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: Would allowing a non sudo user to do mounts be insecure? Is there a better way for the host to share or passthrough a block device?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have actually come across the article you put in your edit before. I have not tried it but it looks like it would work, unfortunately its not the solution im looking for. Currently i think the best way to achieve what im looking for is through a shared folder between the host and container using ` lxc config device add test share disk source=/mnt/drive path=/mnt/drive`

Comment: I do use the shared folder as well. Although the same limitations apply to them: you need to chown the folder/files to uid 100000 so they are owned by the containers root user. Within the container you can then (as root) do a chown to the user that needs access to the folder.